# How to send an email with a excel attachment

Tags: php, excel, email

i am saving excel in folder in my server(note excel is saving in server),i am trying to sent email with an excel attachment that saved in my server,but i didn't receive an email with the attachment(i.e: i received email without an attachment),below is my code please guide me how to do it.

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5'); 
$objWriter->save('/data/data/www/ms/pricelists/newxcelexample.xls');

$my_path ="/data/data/www/ms/pricelists/newxcelexample.xls";

include "class.phpmailer.php"; // include the class file name
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
//$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
$mail->Host = "mail.xichlomobile.com";
$mail->Port = "25"; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "************";
$mail->Password = "**********";
$mail->SetFrom("**************");
$mail->Subject = Test;
$mail->Body = "Test";
$mail->AddAddress("*********");
$mail->AddAttachment($my_path);

 if(!$mail->Send()){
 echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else{
 echo "<span style='font-size:45px;color:#000000;'>Message has been sent</span><br><br>";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you controlled that the file is really present and gets saved correctly? Has the web server the right do read the file (normally readable by the user www-data)?

Perhaps try to supply also the filename to AddAttachment:

```
$mailer->AddAttachment($my_path, basename($my_path));
// or
$mailer->AddAttachment($my_path, basename($my_path), "quoted-printable", "application/vnd.ms-excel") ;
```

If you're using a newer version of PHPMailer, you can also use exceptions to see what's happening. Perhaps it isn't preventing the mail from going out but from attaching the file.

```
try {
    // preparing the email just before the mail->Send()
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
    echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
}
```

Try sending another file for once, e.g. a *.txt or *.zip (to check if you have limitations on the file types you can send, which would be unlikely for a excel file).